# Async ifunction is not waiting for the result

Tags: firebase, function, flutter, dart, async-await

I am building an flutter application. there is signup windows and when user enters the mobile number it check whether it is already registered or not. But the problem is that the function is not waiting for the result from firebase.the function  return true is false if there the user the user doesnot exist.
But here no value is returned

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:zshoperretail/otp_verification.dart';


class mobilewindow extends StatelessWidget {
    TextEditingController mobileController=new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,

      body: Center(
        child:Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:[
        ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        child:Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.white,
        child:TextField(
          maxLength: 10,
          maxLengthEnforced: true,
          controller: mobileController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText:"Mobile Number",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),),),
        SizedBox(height: 5,),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Next",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          onPressed:() =>saveMobile(context),
        )
            ])
      ),
    );

  }
  saveMobile(BuildContext context) async{
    var mobile= mobileController.text;
    mobile="+91"+mobile;
    var result1='';
    result1=await checkMobile(mobile);
    print('check1'+result1);
    if(result1=='false') {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString('mobile', mobile);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => otp_verification()));
    }
    else{
      print(result1);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text("Account already registered.please login."),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          }
      );
    }
  }
  Future<String>checkMobile(String mobile) async{
   FirebaseFirestore firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   var result="";
   firestore.collection('retail_users').doc(mobile).get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot)async{
     if(snapshot.exists){
       print("hello");
       result='true';
     }
     else{
       print("hellno");
       result='false';
     }
   });
   return(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder` and for the `future` parameter give the future function which checks for the mobile number is already registered or not, this will do the job

Comment: Future builder are used for widget right?

Comment: yes, wrap the widgets defined in `body` of `Scaffold` inside the Future Builder

Comment: i dont want wrap it in widget. i just want to execute in in function.

Comment: ....
await firestore.collection(....

Comment: But the functions that you are excuting would  show widgests that you are going to show  if the user is registered or if the user is a first time user of the app, so just wrap those widgets inside a Future builder

Comment: replace `firestore.collection('retail_users').doc(mobile).get().then(...)` with `final snapshot = await firestore.collection('retail_users').doc(mobile).get()`

Answer (score 1):

when your call `.then()` function on a future object it will register the given function to be executed when the data arrive so it is not a good idea to put the `result` inside the callback function. Instead, remove the callback function inside `.then()` and use await.

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection('retail_users').doc(mobile).get();

if(snapshot.exists){
  print("hello");
  result='true';
} else{
  print("hellno");
  result='false';
}

return(result);
```